# Jython Convert List to Array

Tags: java, python, jython

I have a java function I'm trying to call whose signature is:

```
void doStuff(Object...args);
```

I want to call that function from within Jython, however I have my args in a list. I can't find any way to convert my list to an array so I can call this java function that has a variable number of arguments.

Comment: I call variable-argument Java methods from Jython all the time `likeThis(arg1, arg2, arg3)`.  But, perhaps your arguments are *already* in a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go through you list step by step. 
And with every value found, ad that one to the array.

```
for x in list: 
       array.append(x)
```

Comment: Actually passing an array in this fashion still doesn't work because it is only seen as a single arg.